# Large amount of data. Best way to iterate over, without getting memory exhaustion?

Tags: php, laravel, out-of-memory

Using Laravel 6, and so Eloquent Collection classes.

So I have a "lot" of data to process. Roughly 5000 rows, and when fetching it, this generates a Collection of 5000 models. Now each of those models has maybe 20 attributes that need to be read.

Is there a fast way to do this? I currently have an array of the attributes I want to read, and then loops set up like this:

```php
\fopen()...

foreach ($models as $model) {
            $row = [];
            foreach ($this->attributes as $attr) {
                $row[] = \data_get($model, $attr);
            }
        
        \fputcsv($fh, $row);
}

\fclose()...
```

`$models` is a Laravel Collection, created by `EloquentModel::find($ids);` where `$ids` is an array of integers. (5000 ids from the db)

`$this` refers to the class which contains the foreach loops. There is nothing else in this class besides the function that contains the code above, and the `attributes` property which is just an array of strings.

For 5000 rows, each row loops 20 attributes, this can take a very long time to process, and in every case this actually throws a `FatalErrorException:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted`

So what is the fastest way to retrieve the set of attributes for each row? I can't think of a faster one than this nested loop personally.

Additionally, seeing as `\fputcsv()` is writing each line to file, and the `$row` variable is being overwritten each loop, why am I still getting `Allowed memory size exhausted`?

Would a LazyCollection be the solution here?

Thanks!

Comment: where is this code located? and so, what is `$this`?

Comment: "I currently have an array of the attributes I want to read" - `$this` is a class as `$this` usually is, and attributes is an array of strings. Where the code is located doesn't have any relevance that I can think of? It's in my... project? I'm running it as a command in Laravel, so it's just running in cmd line. There's no other code around it besides the fact that `$models` is just a Collection being passed in. The collection is built using Eloquent so whatever Laravel does under the hood.

Comment: Could you give details like, where do you get the $models from(how are you making the query)? I'm asking you to give the details because there may be lot of places, where we could improve the memory being used, as well as the time taken. For e.g You could process the $models in chunks of 100, this would save a lot of memory, as you would only be processing 100 at a time. There could be other places too that might save the memory, so it would be great if you could add details in the post itself

Comment: OK, thanks for explanation, will edit the post. Done!

Comment: Try the solution out and let me know if it works, meanwhile I'll try to find if there's anything elsewhere that can make this efficient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This would process the models in the chunks, 200 at a time, thereby saving a lot of memory.

```
Model::whereIn('id', $ids)->chunk(200, function($models){

      foreach ($models as $model) {
            $row = [];
            foreach ($this->attributes as $attr) {
                $row[] = \data_get($model, $attr);
            }
        
        \fputcsv($fh, $row);
      }
});
```

Comment: Ah interesting! Chunking seems a good idea. I have a question still on this. The collection itself when held in memory doesn't cause the memory limit to be hit. It's actually fairly quick for Laravel to build that collection. Why does it only hit a limit during the loop? Shouldn't all the memory be allocated already before the loop happens?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but what I think is $models already have acquired some memory, which might be huge as we're talking about the collection of Model Instances here, and processing of such big data would also require memory. There could be other ways to improve efficiency. I'm not able to figure out any other as of now. Did the above solution work?

Comment: the chunking is indeed faster, however the foreach loops are taking around 23 seconds to write 200 rows at a time. Now I can't explain every attribute that this runs through as that's probably too many for this post, but I can tell you 5 of them are calculated properties (they do a little math using `bcsub` or `bcmul` to get some total values) This is definitely slowing it down, I will also try removing it and just making sure to read one or two simple properties to see how much those calculations are affecting the speed.

Comment: No they are the same, I'm aware that the array of attributes could potentially be affected by a typo, or an attribute maybe removed and this array would need updating. It's a little legacy and would like to update the way that works whenever I find time. Will try the increased chunk size too. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Okay, if they are the same then you could avoid the loop, and access the attributes using `$model->getAttributes()` But this would give you timestamps, so you can unset($at['created_at']) and other attributes that you may not need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219016/discussion-between-aashish-gaba-and-simonw16).

Comment: You should use _chunkById_ with large datasets. _chunk_ will slow down significantly as you paginate into a large dataset.